# reactJS - How to get rid of hardcoded URL in home.js?

Tags: reactjs, url, hardcode

I have a reactJS application that downloads a report from a hardcoded URL specified in home.js. For testing purposes, I would like to make this a variable. How to do this?

Here's the method in question:

```
  download() {
    // fake server request, getting the file url as response
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = {
            file: "http://10.11.11.11:9080/api/export",
      };
      // server sent the url to the file!
      // now, let's download:
      window.open(response.file);
      // you could also do:
      // window.location.href = response.file;
    }, 100);
  }
```

Here's the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const API_HOST = process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST || '';


class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: undefined
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {cookies} = props;
    this.state.csrfToken = cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch(API_HOST + '/api/user', {credentials: 'include'});
    const body = await response.text();
    if (body === '') {
      this.setState(({isAuthenticated: false}))
    } else {
      this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user: JSON.parse(body)})
    }
  }

  download() {
    // fake server request, getting the file url as response
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = {
            file: "http://10.11.11.11:9080/api/export",
      };
      // server sent the url to the file!
      // now, let's download:
      window.open(response.file);
      // you could also do:
      // window.location.href = response.file;
    }, 100);
  }


  login() {
    let port = (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
    if (port === ':3000') {
      port = ':8080';
    }
    window.location.href = '//' + window.location.hostname + port + '/private';
  }

  logout() {
    fetch(API_HOST + '/api/logout', {method: 'POST', credentials: 'include',
      headers: {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.state.csrfToken}}).then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        window.location.href = response.logoutUrl + "?id_token_hint=" +
          response.idToken + "&post_logout_redirect_uri=" + window.location.origin;
      });
  }

  render() {
    const message = this.state.user ?
      <h4>Welcome, {this.state.user.name}!</h4> :
      <p>Please log in to manage Licenses</p>;

    const button = this.state.isAuthenticated ?
      <div>
        <Button color="link"><Link to="/licenses">Manage Licenses</Link></Button>
        <br/>
        <Button color="link" onClick={this.download}>License Report</Button>
        <br/>
        <Button color="link" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</Button>
      </div> :
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.login}>Login</Button>;

    return (
      <div>
        <AppNavbar/>
        <Container fluid>
          {message}
          {button}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(Home);
```

Comment: why not do exactly like `API_HOST`? Isn't that a variable? You mean runtime variable or static one, or you have some custom logic to come up this variable?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the address as a variable in a file called constants.js
and use environment variables if you have saparate urls for dev and prod
like this

```
export const baseUrl =process.env.IS_DEV==='true'?'https://devUrl.com':'https://prodUrl.com';
```

and use the base url by importing the constants.js file and do this:

```
import {baseUrl} from 'constants.js'

   const response = {
            file: `${baseUrl}/api/export`,
      };
```